# What is the C++ analog of C# byte[]?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, arrays, byte

What is the C++ (and or visual-C++) analog of C# `byte[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest equivalent type in C++ would be a dynamically created array of "unsigned char" (unless you're running on a processor that defines a byte as something other than 8 bits).

So for example

in C#

```
byte[] array = new byte[10];
```

in C++

```
unsigned char *array = new unsigned char[10];
```

Comment: write you are, thank you!) (helped me for my visual-C++ .net library)

Comment: Don't you mean `byte[] array = new byte[10]`?

Comment: Yes thanks for that catch.

I would point out that there are alot of places were C++ and C# arrays differ.  While both can't be resized, C# will give you an error if you try to access more data than is available.  If you're lucky, C++ might crash.

Also, C# can tell you the size of the array at any time, C++ can't tell you how big the array is once its created, you have to remember some how.

Answer (score 12):

`byte[]`, in C#, is an array of unsigned 8-bit integers ([`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.71).aspx)).

An equivalent would be `uint8_t array[]`.

`uint8_t` is defined in stdint.h (C) and cstdint (C++), if they are not provided on your system, you could easily download them, or define them yourself (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio)).

Comment: Though don't name your variables `array`. :)

Comment: or more conventionally, `unsigned char`

Comment: @theatrus, no, `char` is not guaranteed to be a 8-bit type.

Comment: Since `sizeof(char) == 1`, if `char` is not 8 bits, can `uint8_t` technically be 8 bits? Because that would imply `sizeof(uint8_t) < 1`, meaning its not an integer, which would tell us that `size_t` is not an integer type...

Comment: Bytes aren't always 8-bits, of course - it depends on the platform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte).

Comment: @Will A, C#'s `byte` type is guaranteed to be a 8-bit type. 

@mathepic, see [uint8_t vs unsigned char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char)

Comment: @Bertrand: Of course C#'s byte is guaranteed to be 8-bit, as is Java's byte. But in C++ the size of a `char` is platform dependent and if your platform has 16-bit chars I don't see how stdint.h could possibly define `uint8_t` as an 8-bit data type.

Comment: @praetorian: CHAR_BITS >=8. So a char can't be smaller than 8 but it can be larger. uint8_t just has to support 8 bit operations. But who says the compiler need to model uint8_t on a char. http://linux.die.net/man/3/uint8_t

Comment: Matrin York is correct. THe uint8_t should behave as an 8-bit unsigned integer even on systems where a byte != 8-bits. The way it is structured in memory may be different though. On system where a byte = 16 bits, the uint8_t may occupy 16 bits but only perform 8-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @Martin York: I don't get it, the link you posted has `uint8_t` defined as follows: `typedef unsigned char uint8_t`, so it is modeled on a char. If char's are larger than 8 bits, so will the uint8_t. Or am I wrong? All I was saying earlier was that `uint8_t` simply indicates your intention that that variable should only hold values in the range [0 255] but on certain platforms there's nothing stopping you (poor programming practice aside) from sticking larger numbers into it.

Comment: @Praetorian: On this platform it is typedefed as a char as that works for this platform. But there is no standards requirement (I suspect) that it is required to be a char (just that it is required to be 8 bits). Which is another way of saying what  Duracell said.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ standard, `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three available char types. `char` maybe `signed` or `unsigned`, therefore:

```
typedef signed char sbyte;
typedef unsigned char byte;

byte bytes[] = { 0, 244, 129 };
```