# The size of char type on Intel 64 (EM64T) system

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit

I heard somewhere about 16 bit long char type on some of 64 bit systems. What is the size of char type on Intel 64 (EM64T) system?

Comment: You are talking about wchar_t.  Googles really well.

Comment: @Hans, no. "Some systems may define char types to be 16 bits, in which case there probably won't be an 8-bit type of any kind". [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two 64-bit ABIs in common use on EM64T / AMD64 systems:

- The [standard ABI used by Linux](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (and, as far as I'm aware, other Unix variants), which defines `char` as 8 bits (see section 3.1.2).
- The [Windows x64 ABI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx), which also defines `char` as 8 bits (see [Types and Storage -> Scalar Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94z15h2c.aspx)).

But the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) *does* allow a "byte" to be larger than 8 bits, and a `char` is a "byte" (in terms of the C standard) by definition; and such platforms do exist, [e.g. some DSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char/2098444#2098444).

Answer (score 4):

The type `char` has `CHAR_BIT` bits on every implementation. Don't forget to `#include <limits.h>` :)
In `C`, a `char` is always one byte by definition since the size of a byte is implementation dependent.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("A char is %d bits wide (*).\n", CHAR_BIT);
    puts("(*) in this implementation");
    puts("    with the options used for compilation");
    puts("    ...");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am on a 32 bit system. Can I see the output of the code on Intel 64? Thanks

Comment: @ezpresso, that shouldn't matter if you're writing portable code. You _should_ be using CHAR_BIT to take it into account or, at a bare minimum, use the preprocessor to refuse to compile if it's not equal to 8.

Comment: pmg, I changed the wording a little since it seemed to indicate that `byte` was a data type. They're not really synonyms (two different words meaning the same thing), more they just have the same size. Yes, I know that's painfully pedantic (some might even say anal retentive) but that's me :-) I especially loved your caveats in the `puts` output though.

Comment: Thanks @pax. I agree with your pedantism. In `char *ptr = malloc(42);` I allocate 42 **bytes** to use as array of 42 **char** -- they aren't really interchangeable :)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't depend on the ISA, but on the ABI. As far as I know there is no system that defines 1 byte for `char` for x64 programs. At least Windows, Linux and FreeBSD don't.

The official [x86-64](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.pdf) documentation also specifies 1 byte.

Comment: By definition, a char _is_ one byte, the size of the byte is implementation dependent.