# For Apple Implementations (Cocoa/CocoaTouch) is uint8_t always the same type as unsigned char?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

While walking through a sample code application for the iPhone, I found a pair of send/receive methods that effectively had the same signature definitions, with the exception of the value types associated for one of the variables.

From within the header:

```
- (void)receivedData: (unsigned char *)data length:(NSUInteger)len;
- (void)sendData:     (uint8_t*)       data length:(NSUInteger) len;
```

These methods are used as wrappers for a sending/receiving process, which effectively is passing around a pointer to a `byte` array of data being written to and from data streams.   I found these method signatures to be a bit curious and since I'm new to Cocoa/Cocoa Touch dev, I decided to check out the definition of the `uint8_t` type.  I discovered that the `uint8_t` is defined as an `unsigned char` within `stdint.h` and, therefore, the `data` variables for these methods are exactly the same.  At least, that is the case for the `stdint.h` that is being linked within XCode 4.2.

However, doing a bit of further research regarding the `uint8_t` type I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char) regarding `uint8_t` vs. `unsigned char` usage.  The consensus seems to be that quite often these two value types are exactly the same but with some implementations of the C standard libraries, they *might* be different.  Ergo, one should not trust that they will be the same type of data when generating portable code.

With that said, is it safe to assume from within an Apple/Objective-C programming environment that the `uint8_t` will be the same as an `unsigned char` or should I follow the same advice given within the above mentioned question?

This may seem like a picky question to ask, but since I may be integrating libraries where this type of coding mis-conduct appears to be a bit prevalent into a personal codebase that could be used in multiple, Apple environments (for quite a few years to come), I wanted further commentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring questions of portability (as you have implicitly asked us to do), it seems exceptionally unlikely that char will ever be anything other than an eight bit value under Mac OS X and its derivatives such as iOS. I think you can safely assume that unsigned char and uint8_t will be the same forever.

That said, I think as a form of documentation for the programmers to come after you, when you are dealing with a value meant to hold a byte of binary data and not a character, it seems smarter to use "byte" or "uint8_t" or some similar method of indicating to future readers that the intent of a function is to treat a value as a byte and not as a character per se.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe to assume `uint8_t` is a typedef to `unsigned char` on Mac OS X.

For systems that follow POSIX (as Mac OS X), POSIX requires `char` type to be 8-bit.

> (2.12.2 The char Type) "The type char is defined as a single byte; see XBD Definitions (Byte and Character)."

and

> (3.84 Byte) "An individually addressable unit of data storage that is exactly an octet, used to store a character or a portion of a   character; see also Character . A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of 8 bits."

Answer (score 3):

While the C99 standard allows `uint8_t` and unsigned char to be different, in practice, every mainstream operating system - especially UNIX-like systems such as Apple OS family - will have them defined to be the same, for the simple reason that there is just way too much code (pre- and post-C99) that assumes `unsigned char` to be exactly 8 bits wide.

That being said, `uint8_t` is naturally safer from a theoretical standpoint, so there is not much reason not to use it. You don't need to fear any library using `unsigned char`, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that you're fine to use those interchangeably within an Apple environment.  As far as I understand it, the strange implementations which treat `unsigned char` as something other than 8 bytes are few, far between, and in my humble opinion, an idiot ;)

Apple basing their OS on UNIX like bases will almost certainly never change the implementation of `unsigned char`.

Comment: [Some systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standard-committee-cares-about/6972551#6972551)  were around long before Posix defined anything. They might have things like 9-bit bytes, but will also not define `uint8_t` at all, so you will notice.

Comment: I know it was a typo, but it should say "8 bits", not "8 bytes".