# How to use types in embedded C for portable bare metal software

Tags: c, types, embedded, bare-metal, hardware

I'm writing my first bare metal application in C for a specific micro controller. I want to make it as much portable as possible and I'm not sure what is the proper way for using the C types. I have two options in mind:

- Using the typical C standard types such as `char`, `int`, `long` etc.
- Using the types of `stdint.h` for integer types, such as `uint8_t`, `int32_t` etc., and `char` and `double` for the rest of the types.

**Which option is the best one?**

Comment: what is the third option?

Comment: [uint32_t vs int as a convention for everyday programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20077313/2410359) may apply here.

Comment: If you want to write portable code (or any C code really), make sure you understand the misfeature of C that is the *usual arithmetic conversions* and its *integer promotion* rules. They are as important as types themselves.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Reasons to use (or not) stdint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834747/reasons-to-use-or-not-stdint)

Comment: stdint.h simply translates into the native/actual C types char int long.  within a tool for a specific target, the change is rare. but if porting to another platform (of which much if your code wont port anyway) the stdint approach is good.  stdint approach has the problem of a C library which kinda doesnt work with baremetal and depending on the tool can be a PITA (also the problem of how does the C library insure it works with that compiler (sometimes it doesnt)).

Comment: the compiler/toolchain determines what the native types are and for example with gcc there is a toolchain specific include that C libraries can use to get the conversion done right (otherwise the C library is just guessing or hoping they dont change just like you would be using native/real C types).  you could try a hybrid which is not as much of a PITA, use the stdint types but take the header from the toolchain or borrow one from a C library but not necessarily use the C library as much if it is not baremetal without a bunch more work to make your own system.

Comment: Use stdint.h, either `uintn_t` or `uint_fastn_t`. That being said, you need to specify the "best" criteria much more detailed in order to ask such a question here, or answers might just be random opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the well defined integer types of `stdint.h` makes it much easier to port your code to another controller.

for example:
the size of type `int` depends on your machine (16 or 32 bit)

And please remember:
If you wat to work with the MISRA standard, you are not allowed to use the standard types like `int`.

Comment: Mike, I would add that it is only for integer types that must be of a well-defined width. For normal integer calculations, the normal int could probably be used so you can take benefit of a controler with a larger native int type.

Comment: @Paul Ogilivie of course, yes!