# How to make a hexadecimal number from bytes?

Tags: c

I want to compose the number `0xAAEFCDAB` from individual bytes. Everything goes well up to 4 tetrads, and for some reason extra 4 bytes are added with it. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned long int a = 0;

  a = a | ((0xAB) << 0);
  printf("%lX\n", a);
  a = a | ((0xCD) << 8);
  printf("%lX\n", a);
  a = a | ((0xEF) << 16);
  printf("%lX\n", a);

  a = a | ((0xAA) << 24);
  printf("%lX\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `long` is 8 bytes on that platform

Comment: Have you tried it with an unsigned value?

Comment: Welcome to the world of sign extension.  Fortunately, you didn't test with 0X7F or smaller as the first byte.  Using `0xAAUL` would resolve the problem, forcing the `((0xAAUL) << 24)` expression to the type `unsigned long`.  As it stands, `0xAA` is an `int`.

Comment: Not the answer, but you almost never want to use `[unsigned] long`, due to its prominently non-portable size (4 on windows, 8 on linux, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Constants in C [are actually typed](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/01/23/c-type-of-constants/), which might not be obvious at first, and the default type for a constant is an `int` which is a **signed** 32-bit integer (it depends on the platform, but it probably is in your case).

In signed numbers, the highest bit describes the sign of the number: 1 is negative and 0 is positive (for more details you can read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

When you perform the operation `0xAB << 24` it results in a 32-bit signed value of `0xAB000000` which is equal to `10101011 00000000 00000000 00000000` in binary. As you can see, the highest bit is set to 1, which means that the entire 32-bit signed number is actually negative.

In order to perform the `|` OR operation between `a` (which is a 64-bit unsigned number) and a 32-bit signed number, some type conversions must be performed. The size promotion is performed first, and the 32-bit signed value of `0xAB000000` is promoted to a 64-bit signed value of `0xFFFFFFFFAB000000`, according to the rules of the two's complement system. This is a 64-bit signed number which has the same **numerical** value as the 32-bit signed one before conversion.

Afterwards, type conversion is performed from 64-bit signed to 64-bit unsigned value in order to OR the value with `a`. This fills the top bits with ones and results in the value you see on the screen.

In order to force your constants to be different type than 32-bit signed `int` you may use suffixes such as `u` and `l`, as shown in the [website I linked in the beginning of my answer](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/01/23/c-type-of-constants/). In your case, a `ul` suffix should work best, indicating a 64-bit unsigned value. Your lines of code which OR constants with your `a` variable would then look similarly to this:

`a = a | ((0xAAul) << 24);`

Alternatively, if you want to limit yourself to 4 bytes only, a 32-bit unsigned int is enough to hold them. In that case, I suggest you change your `a` variable type to `unsigned int` and use the `u` suffix for your constants. Do not forget to change the printf formats to reflect the type change. The resulting code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned int a = 0;

  a = a | ((0xABu) << 0);
  printf("%X\n", a);
  a = a | ((0xCDu) << 8);
  printf("%X\n", a);
  a = a | ((0xEFu) << 16);
  printf("%X\n", a);

  a = a | ((0xAAu) << 24);
  printf("%X\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

My last suggestion is to not use the default `int` and `long` types when portability and size in bits are important to you. These types are not guaranteed to have the same amount of bits on all platforms. Instead use types defined in the `<stdint.h>` header file, in your case probably either a `uint64_t` or `uint32_t`. These two are guaranteed to be **u**nsigned integers (their signed counterparts omit the 'u': `int64_t` and `int32_t`) while being 64-bit and 32-bit in size respectively on all platforms. For Pros and Cons of using them instead of traditional `int` and `long` types I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837399/5457426) Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = a | ((0xAA) << 24);
```

`((0xAA) << 24)` is a negative number (it is `int`), then it is sign extended to the size of 'unsigned long' which adds those `0xffffffff` at the beginning.

You need to tell the compiler that you want an unsigned number.

```
a = a | ((0xAAU) << 24);
```

```
int main(void) {
  unsigned long int a = 0;

  a = a | ((0xAB) << 0);
  printf("%lX\n", a);
  a = a | ((0xCD) << 8);
  printf("%lX\n", a);
  a = a | ((0xEF) << 16);
  printf("%lX\n", a);

  a = a | ((0xAAUL) << 24);

  printf("%lX\n", a);
  printf("%d\n", ((0xAA) << 24));

  return 0;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fjv19bKGc

Answer (score 2):

`0xAA` gets treated as a *signed* value when it is scaled up during the bit shifting. Since its high bit is 1 (`0xAA` = `10101010b`), the scaled value is **sign extended** to `0x...FFFFFFAA` before you shift and `OR` it to `a`.

You need to cast `0xAA` to an *unsigned* value before bit shifting it, so it gets **zero extended** instead.

Comment: `0xAA` will not be extended to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAA` for sure unless yo declare it as `signed char`, but default type is `int` https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dzcW1Pz6d

Comment: or better example https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gb5xfhrcc