# confusion with data structure allignment?

Tags: c, struct, padding, long-double

Code 1:-

```
struct emp
{
  char a;
  double b;
};
int main()
{
    struct emp e;
    printf("%p    %p", (void*)&e.a, (void*)&e.b);
}
```

Output on my computer:-

```
OO28FF00    0028FF08
```

As the size of `char` and `double` is '1' and '8' respectively and hence the `0028FF00` and `0028FF08` are multiples of '1' and '8' respectively.

Code 2:-

```
struct emp
{
  char a;
  long double b;
};
int main()
{
    struct emp e;
    printf("%p    %p    \n", (void*)&e.a,(void*)&e.b);
}
```

The output is :-

```
0028FF00    0028FF04
```

As the size of `char` and `long double` is '1' and '12' respectively but `0028FF04` is not a  multiple of '12'.

Why padding is not applied in this case?

Comment: First use `%p` instead of `%u` and cast addresses to `void*`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : that I know but my question is regarding padding.

Comment: question is regarding padding and a good question indeed, but using in-proper format type is undefined behavior in C. So I suggest you try again with `%p` and cast addresses to `void*` and update question.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : I did it but the question still remains same.

Comment: correct way is `printf("%p    %p", (void*)&e.a, (void*)&e.b);`

Comment: In my system, `long double` is 16, not 12

Comment: Can you also print `sizeof(long double)`?

Comment: Alignment is not necessarily the same as size.

Comment: @Jay : but in mine its 12

Comment: alignment relates to the native architecture's size, not the structure size. A structure of size 512 bytes would also be aligned to 4/8/16 bytes depending on system, not 512 byte

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : then why in my first example `double` is aligned by 8 bytes not 4

Comment: as far as I can guess is that padding is done in powers of 2, like 1,2,4,8,16.......but 12 in my case is acception

Comment: @kevingomes, maybe you can use `__attribute__((__packed__))` to suppress padding.

Comment: because the FPU loads/stores double in 8 bytes by native, not 4-by-4, or you're specifying `-malign-double` in gcc. 12-byte data may be different because they may need 2 loads, look at or `-m96bit-long-double`

Comment: @Jay : If I supress padding in this question, then this would not be a question.....

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : you mean to say that 12 is stored in parts like 4,4,4

Comment: Which compiler is this?  Is it an old DOS compiler by any chance?

Comment: @Dmitri : mine is mingw gcc and I think that in old compilers, there was no padding facility.

Comment: no, [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is an old feature from the era of RISC, it has come decades before mingw was born

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : but tc is not having alignment...

Comment: In 16-bit DOS times, memory is a constraint so maybe they default to use unaligned data to preserve memory, but it doesn't mean that the compiler don't support padding https://sites.google.com/site/sanselgroup/c/structure-padding

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : but I ran the same code on tc and it did not showed any sign of padding

Comment: Yes, did you read the links on my comment above? They said that the default option is not padding any data, so you have to enable some switch to use it. I don't know x87 assembly so I don't know how they load long double values but [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) said that Pentium or newer prefer long double to be aligned to 8 bytes, maybe you need to change some option to change the alignment mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `long double` is an [80 bit floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) so you need 10 bytes. 10 is really not a very good size though, thus Intel 32 bit processors decided on 12 bytes. 12 is a multiple of 4 which represents 32 bits (3 x 32 bits). This is considered aligned because a 32 bit processor only needs 4 bytes alignment, so the 12 bytes is aligned at any 4 bytes boundary. Obviously, the compiler knows what it's doing and it always tries to generate the smallest possible structure.

This being said, this is where you see that you cannot use a struct declaration and hope to save it as is in a file... at least not with the default C types (you can use int32_t, uint64_t, etc. to get exactly what you want, but there is no equivalent for floating point numbers...)

As someone commented, on a 64 bit architecture, long double is 16 bytes. A waste of 6 bytes... but it makes the type 64 bit aligned all the time.

Comment: No, that's not what Intel decide. Only 32 bit loads/stores on x86 are aligned to 4 byte, not all other data type. And that's just a recommendation, not requirement since they can still operate with unaligned data, althoug with reduce performance. On modern x86 processors, even 32-bit mode requires double to be 8-byte aligned, SSE data must align to 16 bytes, 32 bytes for AVX (and may be 64 bytes for the new AVX-512).

Comment: Yeah... the processor may be setup to accept any alignment, or crash if loading unaligned data with the "wrong" instruction. It's a bit more complicated than I explain here, but the OP only asked about long double and C struct alignment. To learn more about all the subtleties, I'd recommend reading the **Intel 64/IA32 Architectures Software Developers Manual**.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a table of typical alignments:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86

x86 has flexible memory access instructions, so there rules are up to the compiler designers' decision.  We can only imagine why they thought there are the most reasonable.

I found @LưuVĩnhPhúc 's comment very educative.  Although `long double` is 12 bytes on your platform (GCC?) it was 4 bytes aligned by the same reason why a 512 bytes struct will not be 512 bytes aligned;  there will be too much waste in space.  I guess the designers of GCC thought accessing `double` variables should be done in the least possible latency at the cost of some space (up to 7 bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know padding and data alignment heavily depend on the target architecture, compiler optimization options and overall quality of the optimizator. Thus if you don't specifically care about alignment, you get a "quazi-optimal" structures and the compiler is free to decide what is better for this particular set of optimization options (whether -Os or -O is used and so on). If you wish to have a specific alignment, you should use compiler-specific options to tune the things. For GCC and CLang use [`__packed__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute, for MSVC use [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx). See [pragma pack(1) nor __attribute__ ((aligned (1))) works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371296/pragma-pack1-nor-attribute-aligned-1-works) for more info