# Dereferencing a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the below code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct a
{
  void *p;
};

int main(void)
{
  struct a *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
  ptr->p = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
  *((uint8_t *) ptr->p) = 2;
  return 0;
}
```

I am casting the void pointer before dereferencing to avoid the warning

> warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer

Am I breaking any rule by doing this or is this code good?

Comment: What suspicions do you have about rules that might be broken?

Comment: If there's no specific reason why the type of `p` isn't just `uint8_t*`, this is terrible code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb casting the modifiable lvalue? Just wanted to confirm once that this is good or not?

Comment: @Staven Sir this is not the actual code I have in my repo.. Just trying to do something like this. Assume there is already a `void *p` in the stricture and that structure can't be disturbed but want to use it.. This is not a terrible code

Comment: You should `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes sir that care is taken. Casting lvalue was my question and you answered it thanks

Comment: @Gopi technically my answer is wrong if you didn't, so it would be good to update your question to include it

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes edited my question

Comment: `uint8_t` should come with `inttypes.h`, btw.

Comment: @alk Agree.. My question is mostly on the casting part. Yes headers are needed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this code is legal and does not cause undefined behaviour (unless `malloc` returns `NULL`).

Answer (score 3):

As per the standard mandates, this code looks ok. a pointer to a *character type* can be used to point to the object without breaking the aliasing rule.

To quote the standard, chapter §6.3.2.3

> [...]. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

Comment: The code would be OK even if it were not a pointer to character type. Since the object has no declared type, the *effective type* for writing is the type you are using to write with, (and the effective type for reading is the type of the last thing written to the object).   We only write in this example, so we set the effective type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Absolutely sir. I was thinking like if `p` had not been a `void *`, then also, casting to `char *` (or equivalent) and further usage would be defined, right?

Comment: nb: I think uint8_t is not neccessarily character type (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666146/can-uint8-t-be-a-non-character-type)

Comment: @SouravGhosh the type of `p` doesn't matter; the type of the object matters. The object was created by `malloc` so it has no type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry sir, got a bit confused. I thought the type of `p` matters other than being `void *`. Like, if we have `float *p = malloc(sizeof*p);` and then we do `*((int *)p) = 5;` is that case defined?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes that is well-defined , so long as `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(float)`. Writing through `*(int *)p` sets the *effective type* of the object allocated by `malloc` to be `int`.  It would be undefined  to read `*p` subsequently.