# Variable Declaration typedefs conventions in C

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

Ever since I started programming in C I have known/seen everyone to use the following convention when declaring variables using typedefs as shown below:

```
   int32_t *data_value;
   const int16_t *Order_Of_Mag;
   uint16_t min_change;
   uint8_t  eeprom_save_flag;
```

I understand part of the reason is for portability between different architectures. Does anyone know when and/or what standard dictates this method for declaration?

Also what's the recommended method for dealing with standard library (stdio.h) functions that require the use of char, given that a char is neither uint8_t nor int8_t (see example functions below)

```
sscanf(const char *format)
int atio(const char *s)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Everyone is doing it!? Are you doing embedded programming by any chance?

Comment: Check out [Chris Lutz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1725901/418715) answer about `uint8_t` as well as the accepted answer.

Comment: @NPE Apologies I should have said "Everyone I know in the embedded world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only standards that I know of that require you to use such typedefs are project/company specific coding conventions. Those coding conventions then also specify exactly which typedefs (or even macros) to use, so it might be `UINT32` instead of `uint32_t` that you must use

---

As for the choice between `char`, `uint8_t` or `int8_t`, the default should be to use `char` for character data (i.e. strings and characters) and `uint8_t` or `int8_t` for small numbers.