# Generating machine code from C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, hex, jit, machine-code

Sorry if these are naive questions - I have very little understanding of how C really works at the low level.

So I'm generating machine code to write to some mmap'd memory for execution. I'm confused about the use of hexadecimal literals for generating machine code.

Consider the assembly instruction (AT&T syntax): `cmove %edx, %ecx`. This has the machine code representation `0x0F44CA`.

So, would doing something like:

```
char opcode[3] { 0x0F, 0x44, 0xCA };
```

represent the correct binary string under when 'under the hood'? I suspect it might not, since apparently hexadecimal literals in C are stored as integers. My concern is that, since integers are 32-bit, the actual values getting stored are

```
0x0000000F 0x00000044 0x000000CA
```

Which is something completely different from what I need.

Another concern I have is, does the type I give to the array affect the value actually being stored? So would

```
uint8_t opcode[3] { 0x0F, 0x44, 0xCA };
```

or

```
int opcode[3] { 0x0F, 0x44, 0xCA };
```

be any different from

```
char opcode[3] { 0x0F, 0x44, 0xCA };
```

under the hood?

Comment: *"My concern is that, since integers are 32-bit...* Be more specific. On your platform `int` and `unsigned int` are likely 32-bit. Good thing that `char opcode[3]` isn't an `int` array. But your second concern is valid, and I suggest more research ([start with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char)).

Comment: I realize this is nit-picking, but all your array initializations lack the `=` between the `]` and the `{`. Think of initializations as assignments.

Comment: Hexadecimal literals are not stored in any way. That's just source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint8_t opcode[3] = { 0x0F, 0x44, 0xCA };`

will store your values as 8-bit values 'bytes' in the order you gave them.

It is the same as

`unsigned char opcode[3] = { 0x0F, 0x44, 0xCA };`

But using an 'int' type is as you said
0000000F00000044000000CA
or
0F00000044000000CA000000
depending on the endianess of your system.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your actual problem but I think these two points may help you for better understanding of machine code.

1. Use `objdump` and you will get `machine code` and `assembly code`
   together to understand what is happening.

   ```
   objdump -d prog.o
   ```
2. Read this article http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ch3-preview.pdf

I hope this will help you somewhat.