# arduino byte data type, use uint8_t or unsigned char in c?

Tags: c, arduino, char, byte

I'm porting some Arduino code to a mcu in pure c.

The data type `byte` is used in the arduino code which is not supported by the compiler. I'm wondering which data byte should I use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`? Which is more correct? I'm relatively new to coding.

I gather it depends what the intent of the variable.

The variable will store hex data from this camera (screen shot of output).

[sample output](http://learn.linksprite.com/jpeg-camera/tutorial-of-using-linksprite-2mp-uart-jpeg-camera-with-arduino/)

```
byte incomingbyte;
void loop()
{
    byte a[32];
    int ii;
    while(Serial2.available()>0)
    {
        incomingbyte=Serial2.read();
    } 
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You need to be clear what you mean by "hex data". Do you mean you're expecting two hex digits (8 bits of data) in each byte read, or do you mean you're expecting one hex digit (4 bits of data) in each character read? In the former case, you could say the variable will store raw bytes (or raw, 8-bit bytes) from the camera.

Comment: If `byte` is not supported by the compiler, you can either do this `#define byte uint8_t` or you can do this `typedef uint8_t byte;` but either one must be visible to the code modules where `byte` is used.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Abbott I'm expecting two hex digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Byte) an arduino byte is an unsigned 8 bit value. I personally would use the more expressive `uint8_t`, but an `unsigned char` would work as well.

What type is used on the new platform to return a byte received from the serial port?

Might also want to check out this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char)