# How to get byte[] into capnp::Data

Tags: c++, c++11, capnproto

On the official website, there is a [nice and relatively comprehensive example](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html) of how one could use CapnProto for C++ serialisation. What is missing, is how to handle the second Blob type `capnp::Data`, as only `capnp::Text` is covered.

Just for completeness, here is what the Schema Language says about the blob type:

> Blobs: Text, Data
>
> ...
>
> - Text is always UTF-8 encoded and NUL-terminated.
> - Data is a completely arbitrary sequence of bytes.

So, if I have the following schema

```
struct Tiding {
    id @0 :Text;
    payload @1 :Data;
}
```

I can start building my message like this

```
::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message;
Tiding::Builder tiding = message.initRoot<Tiding>();

tiding.setId("1");
```

At this point I got stuck. I can't do this:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

byte data[100];
... //populate the array
tiding.setPayload(data)
//error: no viable conversion from 'byte [100]' to '::capnp::Data::Reader'
```

So I mucked around a bit and saw that capnp::Data is wrapping `kj::ArrayPtr<const byte>`, but I was unable to somehow get a hold of an `ArrayPtr`, much less use it to set the Payload field for my message.

I saw that there is a way to set the default value for the type `Data` (i.e. `payload @5 :Data = 0x"a1 40 33";`), but the schema language doesn't really translate to C++ in this case, so that also didn't help me.

I'd be grateful if somebody could point out what I am missing here. Also, how would I do this if I had `List(Data)` instead of just `Data` as the Payload in my schema?

Comment: Aside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char (question is tagged c++11)

Comment: I am aware of `uint8_t` but the unsigned char typedef is used inside CapnProto (KJ, actually), so I went with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `kj::ArrayPtr` is fundamentally a pair of a pointer and a size.

You can create one by calling `kj::arrayPtr()`, which takes two arguments: a pointer, and the array size. Example:

```
byte buffer[256];
kj::ArrayPtr<byte> bufferPtr = kj::arrayPtr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

`kj::ArrayPtr` has `begin()` and `end()` methods which return pointers, and a `size()` method. So you can convert back to pointer/size like:

```
byte* ptr = bufferPtr.begin();
size_t size = bufferPtr.size();
```

Putting it all together, in your example, you want:

```
tiding.setPayload(kj::arrayPtr(data, sizeof(data)));
```

Comment: An answer by the author himself, awesome! Turns out I already had that, but my IDE (CLion, in this case) kept telling me that there is a `Type parameter mismatch: Class 'kj::ArrayPtr<byte>' is not compatible with class 'capnp::Data::Reader'`. Compiles and runs fine, though. I'm going to investigate and maybe file a bug.

Comment: Odd, there's definitely a constructor defined. BTW, I just realized there's also a `capnp::Data::Reader(ptr, size)` constructor which might confuse CLion less?

Comment: CLion Doesn't complain about the `capnp::Data::Reader(ptr, size)` constructor. Thanks!